# set background image in Jlabel (Label) box with dynamic text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How to set background image in label box with dynamic text.

for example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon("/image/image.png");
label.setText("Text1");
```

This code not working, because The text is not display in in center of image.

Answer (score 4):

Thats very easy.

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class YourFrame extends JFrame {

  private ImageIcon icon;
  private JLabel label;


  public YourFrame(){

    icon = new ImageIcon("/image/image.png");

    label= new JLabel() {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        super.paintComponent(g);
      }
    };

    label.setOpaque(false);
    getContentPane().add( label );

    label.setText("Text1");

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    YourFrame frame = new YourFrame();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set the width and height of the JLabel to be the same dimensions as image.png and align the text in the middle?

Comment: `setPreferredSize` works but is there any other way to do this without manually setting the width and height? (i.e. when I change the .png dimensions, I do not need to modify the codes to fit the .png)

Comment: Then you need to override the getPreferredSize() method of the label and return the icon dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined how the text should be painted in relation to the image. Here are 4 different approaches that don't involve custom painting:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LabelImageText extends JPanel
{
    public LabelImageText()
    {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.ORANGE, 100, 100) );
        label1.setText( "Easy Way" );
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        add( label1 );

        //

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.YELLOW, 200, 150) );
        label2.setLayout( new BoxLayout(label2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        add( label2 );

        JLabel text = new JLabel( "More Control" );
        text.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label2.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
        label2.add( text );
        label2.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(10) );

        //

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.GREEN, 200, 150) );
        add( label3 );

        JLabel text3 = new JLabel();
        text3.setText("<html><center>Text<br>over<br>Image<center></html>");
        text3.setLocation(20, 20);
        text3.setSize(text3.getPreferredSize());
        label3.add( text3 );

        //

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.CYAN, 200, 150) );
        add( label4 );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Add some text that will wrap at your preferred width");
        textPane.setEditable( false );
        textPane.setOpaque(false);
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
        textPane.setBounds(20, 20, 75, 100);
        label4.add( textPane );
    }

    public static class ColorIcon implements Icon
    {
        private Color color;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public ColorIcon(Color color, int width, int height)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getIconWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }

        public int getIconHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
        {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelImageText");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new LabelImageText() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options available. For instance, you can place the JLabel on top of another JLabel (though give the container JLabel a viable layout manager first), or you can draw the image directly in the JLabel's paintComponent method. If you do the latter, be sure the JLabel is set to be opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("background.png"));
label.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Using this icon align center as [background to JLabel](http://www.pointbaba.com/faq/15/display-icon-behind-the-text-in-jlabel-java)