# Can't dispay Text on JLabel having background image

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a JLabel. I just added a background image to it. Now I want to display a text on it.
`label.setText("blabla");` displaying text behind the image. What should I do?

here is my code snippet

```
public Jadmin() {

    setSize(800,500);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setUndecorated(true);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JLabel jl=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("c://image.jpg"));

    jl.setLayout(null);

    add(jl);

    jl.setText("hadsffffffffffffffffffi");

    setVisible(true);
enter code here
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019792/set-background-image-in-jlabel-label-box-with-dynamic-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setIconTextGap(int iconTextGap)` method of JLabel, and set the exact width of your image, but in the negative position, so the text can display OVER the Image if you want.

For Example, if your image width is 125px, set use the method like this: `setIconTextGap(-125)` to display the text over the image.

EDIT: You can do this:

```
ImageIcon bg;

public Jadmin() {

    setSize(800,500);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setUndecorated(true);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JLabel jl=new JLabel();

    bg = new ImageIcon("IMAGE_PATH");
    jl.setIcon(bg);
    jl.setIconTextGap(-IMAGE_WIDTH);
    jl.setOpaque(true);
    jl.setLayout(null);

    add(jl);

    jl.setText("hadsffffffffffffffffffi");

    setVisible(true);
enter code here
   }
```

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: What do you need elaboration on?

Comment: yes working but i need to set the position of the text how can i do this?

Comment: @user3007882 You can use `jl.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CHOOSE_POSITION);` and `jl.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CHOOSE_POSITION);` If that's what you were asking me for...

Comment: but i need to put the text in a (x,y) coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples of different ways to display text on an Icon in a JLabel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LabelImageText extends JPanel
{
    public LabelImageText()
    {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.ORANGE, 100, 100) );
        label1.setText( "Easy Way" );
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        add( label1 );

        //

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.YELLOW, 200, 150) );
        label2.setLayout( new BoxLayout(label2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        add( label2 );

        JLabel text = new JLabel( "More Control" );
        text.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label2.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
        label2.add( text );
        label2.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(10) );

        //

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.GREEN, 200, 150) );
        label3.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        add( label3 );

        JLabel text3 = new JLabel();
        text3.setText("<html><center>Text<br>over<br>Image<center></html>");
        text3.setLocation(20, 20);
        text3.setSize(text3.getPreferredSize());
        label3.add( text3 );

        //

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.CYAN, 200, 150) );
        add( label4 );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Add some text that will wrap at your preferred width");
        textPane.setEditable( false );
        textPane.setOpaque(false);
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
        textPane.setBounds(20, 20, 75, 100);
        label4.add( textPane );
    }

    public static class ColorIcon implements Icon
    {
        private Color color;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public ColorIcon(Color color, int width, int height)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getIconWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }

        public int getIconHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
        {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelImageText");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new LabelImageText() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, you are using JLabel as container :-)